# How to initialize only a slice of a character array?

Tags: c, initialization, slice, array-initialization

I am aware of C's (pretty neat) array initialization syntax, like

```
char arr[12] = {[0] = '\n', [4] = 'z'};
```

to initialize some specific members in the array, but is there a means to initialize a whole chunk of the array with a string? Like so:

```
char filename[12] = {[0..9] = "data/img/"};
```

Is there a built-in syntax that allows it? Or do I have to stick to *memcpy()*:

```
char filename[strlen(basename) + 14];
memcpy(filename, "data/img/", 9);
memcpy(filename + 9, basename, l);
memcpy(filename + 9 + l, ".bmp", 4);
filename[l + 13] = '\0';
```

is what I currently have; *filename* is the incriminated character array, and *basename* a variable string.

Comment: I think the question might become clearer if you ask about e.g. `[3..9]`, slices from `[0]` are less interesting. Or are they what you are actually asking about?

Comment: Yeah they are, I want a string that starts with constant characters, and after that append other (variables) characters

Comment: then [edit] your question it's ambiguous and someone partially answered already.

Comment: btw: if the rest was initialized to 0 and the offset != 0 then the string would become an empty string with some junk in the middle. Not that interesting.

Comment: If the offset _isn't_ 0, well, think about a buffer containing a string _in the middle_ on a zeroed string. How are we supposed to handle that?

If you print it, you get a blank because it _starts_ with 0.

This is a binary string now. this syntax isn't designed for C-strings (nul terminated, and non-nul before)

Comment: BTW I'm using a VLA. It might complicate things (Antti Haapala's solution does not work)

Comment: Do you really need VLA? If you are on typical hosted system, it's likely that you can afford `malloc`. If you are on embedded system, it's likely that you have to reserve enough stack space for worst case anyway.

Comment: "*I'm using a VLA*" you really should have mentioned this in your question. Especially as the two 1st examples you give would not work with VLAs!

Comment: you might want to look at `strcpy()` and `strcat()`.  They are exposed via the `string.h` header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use variable-length arrays, initialisation is out of the question, but why not use `snprintf`instead of the `memcpy` chain with hand-calculated offsets?

```
snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "data/img/%s.bmp", basename);
```

If you don't want to calculate the dimension of your VLA by hand, you can call `snprintf` with a null destination and let it calculate the resulting string length for you:

```
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "data/img/%s.bmp", basename);
char filename[len + 1];
```

(But make sure that you use the same format string and arguments for both calls.)

Comment: In addition, if strings are mostly small, it's possible to use good guess for stack allocated buffer in first `snprintf`, and if that is not enough, then `malloc` necessary size and do `snprintf` again. That would avoid double call in most cases.

Comment: Note: unfortunately snprintf() returns a signed integer value.

Comment: @joop:Oh, yes. That would blow the stack if if returned a negative value to indicate an error. Fixed that.

Comment: The "fixed" code is still UB if a negative value is returned; technically you should check for that

Comment: for the first call, wouldn't sprintf suffice?

Comment: So much for quick fixes.

Comment: In most cases, an oversized buffer[PATH_MAX] + sprintf() is good enough, IMHO.

Comment: @joop: Yes, I wouldn't have used a VLA here, but added it for "completeness" and because the hard-coded in the OP's post are really pitfalls when the dirname changes. I'm having a hard time to find out under which conditions `snprintf` returns −1. Passing the wrong number of types of arguments is UB and can't be detected. Using nonsensical flags (`%hs`) gives a compiler warning, but `snprintf` silently ingnores them. The man pages aren't very instructive either.

Comment: Doesn't work with sprintf -- just tried it, got segfault.

Comment: I think the -1 return is allowed  to support pre-standard implementations. Some of these never returned a value >= 2nd argument.

Answer (score 4):

(Notice to all downvoters, this answer was written *18* minutes before the edit that added the info about VLAs)

What's wrong with

```
char arr[12] = "string";
```

which would initialize elements **0** .. **5** with the characters of `"string"`, element **6** with the terminating NUL and sets the rest to setting the rest to NUL as well.

GCC has an extension, wherein you can initialize a range of an array with a *single* value, i.e.

```
char arr[12] = {[1 ... 7] = 'a'};
```

but it doesn't work with a string.

---

Initializers do not work with variable length arrays, at all. Use `sprintf` in that case.

Comment: Perhaps he's more after: `char arr[12] = {[1..7] = "string"};`? Or alike. Didn't DV, BTW.

Comment: @joH1 thanks also for making the question into a chameleon <g>

Answer (score 1):

Although this works:

```
const char * basename = "base";

char filename[strlen(basename) + 14];
memcpy(filename, "data/img/", 9);
memcpy(filename + 9, basename, l);
memcpy(filename + 9 + l, ".bmp", 4);
filename[l + 13] = '\0';
```

It's complicated and error prone.

For "strings" (`'\0'`-terminated `char`-arrays) there is the `str*()` family of functions around.

Use it like this:

```
char filename[strlen(basename) + 14]; 
strcpy(filename, "data/img/"); /* Sets filename including the final 0. */
strcat(filename, basename); /* Appends to filename including the final 0.  */
strcat(filename, ".bmp"); /* ditto */
```

Comment: @joH1: Please note that the first call is not to `strcat()`  but to to `strcpy()`.

Comment: Yep I've seen it. It could have been a subtle but pull-your-hair-out bug, though

Comment: `snprintf` or `sprintf` , IMO, would be less error-prone than either of these

Comment: @M.M: If run twice, yes.

Comment: You solution is O(n²) not really the purpose of C

Comment: @Stargateur: Good point on O(n²), indeed. The purpose of C is arguable ... ;-)

Comment: @alk Indeed, "use case" will be more appropriate I suppose.